# rebar eunit can't find include lib in erlang:latest docker container

Tags: docker, erlang, eunit

I'm new to docker and erlang. I've installed docker and VSCode on my windows machine and I want to learn to develop erlang in the container, so I created Dockerfile:

```
FROM erlang:latest

WORKDIR /project

COPY . .
```

and .devcontainer directory with
devcontainer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Erlang dev container",
    "context": ".",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "settings": { 
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "extensions": []
}
```

After I opened my project folder in container I can issue bash commands and I can start erl but when I try to ask rebar to test my code with

```
rebar eunit
```

or

```
rebar3 eunit
```

I get error:

```
can't find include lib "eunit/lib/eunit.hrl"
```

What did I do wrong? Is the erlang:latest image supposed to be used for erlang development? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `eunit`, when I run erlang programs in the shell (not using docker), I use the following `-include_lib` directive:

```
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
```

You seem to be using a different path:

```
 eunit/lib/eunit.hrl
```

> in container I can issue bash commands

Then use bash commands to search for the file `eunit.hrl`.

You can always just copy the file [eunit.hrl](http://erlang.org/download/eunit.hrl) and put it in the `src` directory of your rebar project, then in your module use:

```
-include("eunit.hrl")
```

> I'm new to docker and erlang.

If worst comes to worst, don't worry about eunit.  There is a lot to learn about erlang before you will need a testing framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, that was it, eunit/lib/eunit.hrl instead of eunit/include/eunit.hrl, now my tests have passed!